# How to create multi value selection in column Report Id using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, spagobi

SQL Query -

```
select REPORT_ID,CASE_NUM,REPORT_DUE_DATE,REPORT_SUBMISSTION_DATE,REPORT_SUBMISSION_USER_ID
from CLINICALDW.ESM_TABLE 
Where REPORT_ID In (?)
```

JavaScript -

```
this.queryText =
this.queryText.replace("100415",params["ReportId"].value.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdHyX.jpg)

Use this java script code and make Lov Driver as Number

Comment: code posted as image is not very useful . Readers can't copy it, for a start.